# Update field inside document by id in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to add (+1) a qty field inside a collection with documents like this:

```js
    {"_id": { "$oid" : "531cc2410b4ebf000036b2d7" },
   "name": "ALMACEN 2",
   "items": [
        {
          "id": "111111",
          "marca": "BJFE",
          "tipo": 0,
          "color": "GDRNCCD",
          "mano": 1,
          "modelo": 0,
          "qty": 1
        },
        {
          "marca": "BJddFE",
          "tipo": 0,
          "color": "GDffRNCCD",
          "mano": 1,
          "modelo": 0,
          "qty": 3
        },
        {
          "marca": "BJeeFE",
          "tipo": 0,
          "color": "GDRNCCD",
          "mano": 1,
          "modelo": 0,
          "qty": 9
        }   ] }
```

I want to add +1 to qty in the document with _id = 531cc2410b4ebf000036b2d7 and inside items, with id=1111.

Is it possible?

EDIT:

with this code

```js
warehouses.update(
    {_id: new ObjectID(warehouseId)},
    {"$inc": { "items.$.qty": -1 }},
     function (e, docs) {
        if (e) {
            error(e);
            return;
        }

        success(docs);
    });
```

I have error:

> cannot apply the position operator without a corresponding query field containing an array

Finally this works:

```
 warehouses.update({_id: new ObjectID(warehouseId), "items.id": itemId}, {"$inc": { "items.$.qty": -1 }}, function (e) {
        if (e) {
            error(e);
            return;
        }

        success();
    });
```

Comment: This will not work. You **must** match *something* in the array in order to use a positional operator. The code example I gave in my answer was **clear** on this (bold text in the answer). So if you **do not do exactly** what I have stated then this operation will fail. As it has by the *misinterpretation* you have demonstrated here. Please do what I actually said instead.

Comment: How can that work? the _id constructor should be ObjectId (capitalized)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Just use [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) and the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { _id: <matching id>, "items.id": 1111 },
    { "$inc": { "items.$.qty": 1 } }
)
```

The `$` matches the index of the element you **matched** in the query part of your update. This allows the *update* portion of the statement to know which element in the array to address.

Comment: I have an error:  cannot apply the position operator without a corresponding query field containing an array

I edit with the code of the request

Comment: @colymore not if you submitted a query like I did above you won't. It is true that you **must match** an element in the array with your query selection. Here I referenced the "items.id" in order to match **one** of the elements in the array. If this does not work for you then you are doing something **very** different. And perhaps should update your question with that edit when you do. Notify me with a comment here.

Comment: This works, the finnaly code its in the question. thanks